# Can't connect to local MariaDB running with Docker with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, docker-compose, pdo, mariadb

I have a local Docker compose stack with MariaDB, PHP-FPM and Nginx running on my machine for local development.
I can successfully access the webpages served by Nginx on http://localhost:8080/ on my browser.
I can also successfully connect to the database using TablePlus, a local GUI DB browser, on host 127.0.0.1, port 8889. It works with user `root` and password `root` (but weirdly enough not with any other user set as the MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD env variables I catch in the Docker compose).

Anyway, when I try to connect with PHP/PDO using the following PHP code, same credentials:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=words', 'root', 'root');
```

...I get `Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

EDIT: and when I use:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889;dbname=words', 'root', 'root');
```

...I get `Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

Why?

(Here is my Docker compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    container_name: mariadb-10.5
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      # port 3306 is the default port for mariadb, forwarded to 8889 on the local machine
      - 8889:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

  php-fpm:
    image: bitnami/php-fpm:7.4
    container_name: phpfpm-7.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ${WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/app

  nginx:
    image: bitnami/nginx:1.20
    container_name: nginx-1.20
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/logs:/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/
      - ./nginx/server-blocks/default.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/default.conf:ro
      - ${WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/app
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - php-fpm
```

)

Comment: When the host name is "localhost", PHP PDO uses a Unix domain socket instead of a TCP socket.  Try using "127.0.0.1" instead.

Comment: Try some of these things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory First remarks also make me think flush / restart of database might not be a bad option.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say I also tried with 127.0.0.1. I edited my question.

Comment: The user credentials in the database are tied to client `user@localhost` or `user@10.%` for eg. as to differing responses. Firewall, Selinux, probably need to narrow it down more, I'm also ignorant to any Docker aspects.

Comment: I still don't understand why I would work with a GUI client and not PHP/PDO with same credentials.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71124488/connection-refused-mariadb-in-docker), ports are ignored for connections between containers, so use 3306, and the host name is the mariadb container name `mariadb-10.5`. `MYSQL_USER` does create a `$MYSQL_USER@%` user so that will be accessible.

Comment: @danblack Well spotted! It works. I think you should post a StackOverflow answer  with this

Comment: glad to help. Just too short on time to do it properly. You're welcome to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered by [@danblack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10195153/danblack), since the connection to the DB is done from inside a Docker container to another container:

1. Connections between containers always use not remapped ports. So the connection to the DB container needs to use internal, MariaDB standard port 3306 - not the remapped, exposed 8889 port.
2. The host name of the DB must be the DB container name (in this case, the
   MariaDB container name `mariadb-10.5`), not `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

So all in all the PHP/PDO connection object becomes:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=mariadb-10.5;dbname=words', 'root', 'root');
```